# Overlay timeseries lines from different years for the same site

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, lubridate

I want to compare the water levels at the same site across 3 years. So I want to plot these 3 years on the same graph. The data are collected twice a day during the spring, and the dates and times for the data points are stored as POSIXct date format using lubridate.

For example:

```
library(lubridate)
yr <- c(rep("2012", 128), rep("2013", 136), rep("2014", 112))
mt <- c(c(rep("5", 62), rep("6", 60), rep("7", 6)),
        c(rep("5", 58), rep("6", 60), rep("7", 18)),
        c(rep("5", 50), rep("6", 60), rep("7", 2)))
dy <- c(c(rep(1:31, each = 2), rep(1:30, each = 2), rep(1:3, each = 2)),
        c(rep(3:31, each = 2), rep(1:30, each = 2), rep(1:9, each = 2)),
        c(rep(7:31, each = 2), rep(1:30, each = 2), rep(1, each = 2)))
hr <- c(rep(c("2:00", "14:00"), 64),
        rep(c("2:00", "14:00"), 68),
        rep(c("2:00", "14:00"), 56))
water.levels <- data.frame("Date" = ymd_hm(paste(yr, mt, dy, hr, sep = " ")),
                       "Levels" = runif(376, min = 0.8, max = 1.5))
```

When I plot, I get the three years on the same graph, but as one continuous time series:

```
plot(water.levels, type = "l")
```

Instead, I would like them overlayed, since the data are all collected during comparable times of the year. So far I have not found a solution for this.

Thank you!

Comment: IIRC, do you want a ts for 2012, one for 2013, and one for 2014?

Comment: yes, but all overlayed in one graph, like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LqYa.png

Comment: You are specifying the year in the x-axis when you use `"Date" = ymd_hm(paste(yr, mt, dy, hr, sep = " ")`, which makes the annual series show up on a timeline next to each other. I'd suggest instead you use a single year for all the series, e.g. `"Date" = ymd_hm(paste(2014, mt, dy, hr, sep = " ")` and map the year to color.

Comment: aha! thanks! that works!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jon Spring, here was a simple enough solution:

```
water.levels <- data.frame("Date" = ymd_hm(paste(1970, mt, dy, hr, sep = " ")),
                           "Year" = yr,
                           "Levels" = runif(376, min = 0.8, max = 1.5))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(water.levels, aes(Date, Levels, 
                         group = factor(Year), 
                         colour = factor(Year))) +
geom_line()
```